# releasing modules with threaded classes and controlling them python

Tags: python, multithreading, module, command-line-arguments

Basically I'm building an application that has a couple of numbered options for you to pick from.

It's named *main.py*, I wrote standalone modules for each possible option so I can run the modules seperately. Now this one module I wrote It contains a threaded class. a problem I'm having when I command : `python mod_keepOnline.py` is that it does not pass control back to the terminal |AND|  When I run the module trough *main.py*, *main.py* stops listening for a new choice to pick. I know it's because of the threads. I was wondering how I can "let the threads manage their own after they have been spawned". So get back control from `mod_keepOnline.py` to the terminal or main script.

I also want to be able to kill the released threads again.

something like `mod_keepOnline.py -killAll`

Uhm heres my code :

```
###########################################
################## SynBitz.net ############
import threading
import objects
import time
import mechanize
import os
import gb
##########################################
class Class_putOnline (threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self,person,onlineTime):
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)
        self.startTime = time.time()
        self.alive = True
        self.person = person
        self.onlineTime = onlineTime
        self.firstMessage=True
    def run(self):
        while(self.alive):
            if(self.firstMessage):
                print self.person.getInfo() + " SPAWNED ONLINE"
                self.firstMessage=False

            self.person.login()
            time.sleep(300)
            self.person.logout()
            if((time.time()-self.startTime) > self.onlineTime):
                print self.person.getInfo() + " SPAWNED OFFLINE "
                self.alive = False
                self._Thread__stop()
#########################################              
def main():
    for line in open(gb.accFile,"r"):
        gb.accountList.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
    for account in gb.accountList:
        gb.accountInfo = account.split('|',4)
        browser =  mechanize.Browser()
        browser.set_handle_robots(False)
        browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
        browser.set_handle_referer(True)
        browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]  
        gb.spiderList.append(objects.spider.Bot(gb.accountInfo[0],gb.accountInfo[2],gb.accountInfo[1],gb.accountInfo[3],browser))
    if gb.accountInfo[2] not in gb.distros:
        gb.distros.append(gb.accountInfo[2])
    onlineAccounts = []
    for index, acc in enumerate(gb.spiderList):
        onlineAccounts.append(Class_putOnline(acc,115200)) # 600*6*8*4= 28800 = 8 uur 3600 test seconds = 1 h (1200 seconds for test time of 20 minutes...  )
        time.sleep(0.1)
        onlineAccounts[index].start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I open a ssh session to my server and run a python script, even when I run it in background, it dies after I close my session. How do i keep my scripts running when I'm not connected?

Comment: There is no way to fix this, without running the program a different way (Best way would be a manual cronjob, as Tyson suggested).
Perhaps you could tell us what your module is trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> When I open a ssh session to my server and run a python script, even when I run it in background, it dies after I close my session. How do i keep my scripts running when I'm not connected?

Run it as a cronjob, and manually start the cronjob if you need to run script on demand.

> Ok I'm pretty new to python

Me too.

EDIT:
Quick tip, use """ for long comments.

Example:

"""Description:

This does this and that and extends this and that. Use it like this and that.

"""

Answer (score 0):

as I understand:

When you run a process then the input and output of the terminal is redirected to the process input and output.

If you start threads this will not change anything with this. The process has the terminal in and output as long both exist. What you can do is send this program to the background (with control-z).

If you run a program, it has its own namespace. You can import a module and change attributes of it but this will never change the module in another program.

If you want to have two programs, One is in the background running all the tine (eg with jobs as proposed by Tyson) and one from the command line, you need to communicate between those two processes.

Maybe there are other ways to circumwent the borders of processes but i do not know them.

Therefore I wrote this module where I can store values in. Everytime a value is stored directly, the state of the module is saved to disk.

```
'''
This is a module with persistent attributes

the attributes of this module are spread all over all instances of this module
To set attributes:
    import runningConfiguration
    runningConfiguration.x = y

to get attributes:
    runningConfiguration.x

'''

import os
import types
import traceback

fn = fileName = fileName = os.path.splitext(__file__)[0] + '.conf'

class RunningConfiguration(types.ModuleType):

    fileName = fn

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        types.ModuleType.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        import sys
        sys.modules[__name__] = self
        self.load()

    def save(self):
        import pickle
        pickle.dump(self.__dict__, file(self.fileName, 'wb'))

    def load(self):
        import pickle
        try:
            dict = pickle.load(file(self.fileName, 'rb'))
        except EOFError:
            pass
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
        else:   
            self.__dict__.update(dict)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
##        print 'set', name, value,
        l = []
        v1 = self.__dict__.get(name, l)
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        try:
            self.save()
##            print 'ok'
        except:
            if v1 is not l:
                self.__dict__[name] = v1
            raise

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        import types
        if name in ('__dict__', '__class__','save','load','__setattr__',                    '__delattr__', 'fileName'):
            return types.ModuleType.__getattribute__(self, name)
##        print 'get', name
        self.load()
        l = []
        ret = self.__dict__.get(name, l)
        if ret is l:
            if hasattr(self.__class__, name):
                return getattr(self.__class__, name)
            if name in globals():
                return globals()[name]
            raise AttributeError('%s object has no attribute %r' %                                  (self.__class__.__name__, name))
        return ret

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self.__dict__[name]
        self.save()




RunningConfiguration(__name__)
```

I saved it to runningConfiguration.py.

You can use it like this:

```
# program1
import runningConfiguration
if not hasattr(runningConfiguration, 'programs'):
    runningConfiguration.programs = [] ## variable programs is set
runningConfiguration.programs+= ['program1'] ## list is changed and = is used -> module is saved
```

This is an insecure module and not everything can be saved to it, but many things.
Also when two modules save at the same time the first written values may get lost.

Try it out: import ist from two different programs and see how it behaves.